# How do I fix failure code: "overfull\vbox(46.80006pt too high) detected at line 28" ? Line 28 is line above \end{table}

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|ll|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tittel (norsk og engelsk):\\    \\  \\    \\ Test og analyse av MES for vareproduksjon\\    \\  \\    \\  \\    \\ Sensors for condition-monitoring of roll   crusher\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Prosjektnummer:\\    \\  \\    \\ 2\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Forfattere:\\Niklas Nordrik\\Ola Ims Winther \\ Sondre Mjøs\\Steffen Røstad\\
\end{tabular}}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Dato:\\    \\ 19.01.2022\end{tabular} \\ \cline{2-2} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Gradering:\\    \\ Konfidensiell\end{tabular}     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Studieretning: Maskiningeniør – Drift og vedlikehold}                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Veileder internt: Viggo Pedersen}                                                    \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Oppdragsgiver: Mjøs Metallvarefabrikk}                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Veileder eksternt: Magnus Mjøs}                                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sammendrag:\\ \\ I dette prosjektet skal vi\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Stikkord:\\ \\ MES\\ Produksjonsovervåkning\\ Cybersikkerhet\end{tabular}} &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Keywords:\\ \\ MES\\ Production monitoring\\ Cyber security\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You have not provided any code to allow anyone to reproduce the warning, it is just telling you that something is 47pt too large to fit on the page.  I would start by removing `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` (scaling tables leads to inconsistent font sizes and should almost always be avoided) and removing `[H]` (which will allow the table to float to find a better page.

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the resizebox, then the warning moves to the line with "Forfattere", and we see that the problem is you have 6 lines in a `\multirow{2}`.  You need to increase that 2 to account for the height of the cell; 5 turns out to be sufficient.

But you shouldn't use multirow for text that falls on the lines anyway, and `\multicolumn{1}` is always a red flag.  I was able to delete a lot of that and end up at the following that renders identically:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Tittel (norsk og engelsk):&\\&\\&\\
&Prosjektnummer:\\
Test og analyse av MES for vareproduksjon&\\&\\&\\
&2\\&\\&\\
Sensors for condition-monitoring of roll crusher&\\ \hline
&Dato:\\
Forfattere:&\\
Niklas Nordrik&19.01.2022\\\cline{2-2}
Ola Ims Winther&Gradering:\\
Sondre Mjøs&\\
Steffen Røstad&Konfidensiell\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Studieretning: Maskiningeniør – Drift og vedlikehold}\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Veileder internt: Viggo Pedersen}\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Oppdragsgiver: Mjøs Metallvarefabrikk}\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Veileder eksternt: Magnus Mjøs}\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Sammendrag:}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{I dette prosjektet skal vi}\\\hline
Stikkord:&Keywords:\\
&\\
MES&MES\\
Produksjonsovervåkning&Production monitoring\\
Cybersikkerhet&Cyber security\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```